# Issues when statically linking with libmysqlclient.a. Seems to be intended for only programs written in C++

Tags: mysql, c, linux, static-linking

Writing a program in C.  Compiles and runs just fine when linking with dynamic (shared) libraries.  Need to create a version linked statically to make this program as portable as possible.

Using simple "make" in Ubuntu (ver 18).  Below is the "build" part of the "makefile".  The important library is "libmysqlclient.a" static library.  Have used 3 methods to determine what other static libraries need to be included:

1. mysql_config
2. pkg-config
3. ldd (technically this is for dynamic linking but worth trying to be complete)

Found several needed static libraries (see below).  In researching all of this, I also found comments like:

- the order of the static libraries in the make command is important.  It did fix or break attempts at building until I arrived with the order below.
- in some cases a static library may need to be included than once because of other involved static libraries.  this also fixed some errors

These are the reasons why they are ordered as shown and why some (like lpthread are included more than once).  I also included complete paths for the static libraries (even though there is another way to deal with that).

Ran "make" and got hundreds of errors.  A large number of them like the ones below:

undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)' undefined reference to` operator delete(void*)'

One of the actual errors looked like this:

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(my_file.cc.o): in function `MyFileInit()': (.text._Z10MyFileInitv+0x1c): undefined reference to` operator new(unsigned long)'

So the static library causing the error seems to be libmysqlclient.a

This seemed odd.  These are C++ constructs and my code is just plain C, neither is ever called in my code (I use malloc and free).  The compiler I specified (cc) is a simple C compiler.  So as a wild guess, I added the following static libraries:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a

And this resolved the errors.  My program now links (with a few warnings).  But "seg faults" when I run the program.

Is there a "libmysqlclient.a" static library for just C?  Or some other way around this problem?  Or am I totally missing something else?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the makefile (with SOURCES and OUT sections removed due to proprietary information):

CXX = cc

CFLAGS = -Wno-unused-variable -Bstatic
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -Iinclude -I/usr/include/mysql
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9

Here's the build part of the makefile:

```
$(CXX) -o $(OUT) $(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

Comment: The fact that you are using `CXX` is suspicious. That's the variable make uses for C++ compilation. `CC` is for C code. So possibly there are other parts of your build that is in fact C++. Hard to say with the info you have provided. It would be best if you could provide a [mre].

Comment: "My program now links (with a few warnings)" -- Please show us the *complete and unedited* text of the warnings.

Comment: The libmysqlclient.a can be provided by [libmysqlclient-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmysqlclient-dev) or [libmariadb-dev-compat](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmariadb-dev-compat), which one do you have installed? They are meant to be ABI compatible so you could try the other one. From the package pages links to the bug reports and I cannot see anything similar.

Comment: It looks like libmysqlclient is *implemented* in C++, which means there's no way to avoid the need for the C++ runtime. I would strongly recommend you reconsider your choice to attempt to statically link this program -- static linkage just plain doesn't work as well as dynamic linkage on Linux (mainly because nobody tests it).

Comment: CXX is not the actual compiler but a substitution flag.  The actual compiler is "cc", identified in the makefile I included just above CFLAGS.  Will included all of the warnings in a following response.  Installed "libmysqlclient-dev".  We can NOT use dynamic libraries.  Our code runs on machines that may not have all of the shared object libraries we'd otherwise need.  We know static makes an executable much larger, but it also makes it more compatible.  And yes, it does appear that Linux doesn't support static linkage as well as hoped.

Comment: Can't include a complete-unedited list of warnings.  Exceeds character limit by over a thousand charcters.  So a sample of warnings:  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.cc.o): in function `mysql_load_plugin_v':
(.text.mysql_load_plugin_v+0x175): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

Comment: This list of warnings becomes a lot bigger if I remove the C++ static libraries. And includes a lot of errors.  And does not successfully build an executable

Comment: @GGS Did you know you can edit your question? The tiny gray word "edit" under the tags is a button. (Yes, it's bad UI design. Stack Exchange doesn't seem to care.)  Use that to show us the complete-unedited list of warnings.

Comment: Thx for the info on editing a question.  I tried to add an unedited list of warnings and errors.  Unfortunately, there is a 30,000 character limit on that and the list I have consists of 166,000+ characters.  Have tried some additional CFLAGS which may have added more errors-warnings.  Will remove them and try again.  Removing the additional flags only made it worse.